# EPSG Tranformation in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, openlayers

I'm migrating from **OpenLayers** to **Leaflet** library and I got this issue:

OpenLayers code transforms `EPSG:4326` coordinates to `EPSG:3857` doing

```
var arCoordinates = ol.proj.transform(iarClickCoordinates, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
```

> **how can I do that in Leaflet?**

Using Leaflet 1.3.0

I google it but there's no much information.

Thank's

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [list of Leaflet plugins](http://leafletjs.com/plugins), you'll find a link to [proj4leaflet](https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet) which allows to load other CRSs in Leaflet. And from there you can find some links to [proj4js](https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js), which allows you to programmatically convert coordinates.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: Man, examples are literally two clicks away at https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js#using